# ament_export_dependencies(Boost) not working?

Tags: ros2, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a library that depends on boost, and it doesn't seem like boost is properly being pulled in as a recursive dependency. How do I properly export the dependency on boost for downstream packages?

My build fails with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/slam_karto.dir/src/slam_karto.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6detail23get_current_thread_dataEv'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.65.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [slam_karto] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/slam_karto.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< slam_karto [ Exited with code 2 ]
```

From my library CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(open_karto)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
include_directories(include)
add_library(karto SHARED src/Karto.cpp src/Mapper.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(karto Boost)
ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_libraries(karto)
ament_export_dependencies(Boost)
```

From the consuming package CMakeLists.txt:

```
ament_target_dependencies(slam_karto
  open_karto
  )
```

I can make the error go away by changing the consuming package to have the following, but this is very bad practice:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
ament_target_dependencies(slam_karto
  open_karto
  Boost
  )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331089/ament_export_dependencies(boost)-not-working?/) by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2019-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The API docs of the `ament_export_dependencies` functions (https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/95cab1de1cd6bd7caad34d0122e11b2e86310ee2/ament_cmake_export_dependencies/cmake/ament_export_dependencies.cmake#L16-L23) describes the requirements what you can pass to it.

In your case of using `Boost` and requiring the component `thread` a simple `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)` call isn't sufficient. Since the API doesn't know about the `COMPONENTS thread` part it won't use it when downstream packages find your package and as a consequence they will fail to find the Boost thread symbols.

You will need to create a custom CMake file which finds the right component of Boost and register that file as a `CONFIG_EXTRAS` (see https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/95cab1de1cd6bd7caad34d0122e11b2e86310ee2/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package.cmake#L24-L32).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on 2019-09-07**:
So what needs to go in the custom CMake file for Boost? What properties are being ignored by ament's dependency mechanism?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-09-08**:
Since ROS 2 tried to use newer C++ features instead of Boost where possible I don't have an example at hand. A similar case exporting TinyXML2 instead of Boost can be found here: https://github.com/ros/pluginlib/blob/bc325fb355672a499710acbe87fd43ae4f4714dd/pluginlib/CMakeLists.txt#L122-L124 and https://github.com/ros/pluginlib/blob/bc325fb355672a499710acbe87fd43ae4f4714dd/pluginlib/pluginlib-extras.cmake#L39-L41

**Comment by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on 2019-09-08**:
Thanks! I wrote up an issue here: https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/issues/199

It would be nice to have a solution in ament rather than coding up a wrapper for each component-based CMake package. I definitely don't have the knowledge right now to make a PR myself.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2020-09-29**:
is finally the idea of `ament_export_dependency_with_components` something to explore?
I imagine something like: `ament_export_dependency_with_components(Boost COMPONENTS thread)`

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-09-29**:
Cross posted question: https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/issues/282

**Comment by [felixf4xu](https://answers.ros.org/users/120001/felixf4xu/) on 2023-07-21**:
quick code example: https://github.com/ros-planning/geometric_shapes/pull/205/files

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue trying to port a package from ROS1 to ROS2. After some research, I figured out following way helps to link the Boost libraries correctly.

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
  system 
  thread 
  program_options
)

target_link_libraries(myPackage
                      ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

ament_target_dependencies(myPackage 
                          rclcpp
                          geometry_msgs)
```

---

Originally posted by [mjm522](https://answers.ros.org/users/25029/mjm522/) with karma: 46 on 2020-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1